# Microsoft Search Custom Result sorting in _layouts/15/search.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-search

i couldn't find anything in Microsoft Documentation about sort order (sortProperties) in Microsoft Search for ExternalItems. I would like to be able to order by creationdate of items in _layouts/15/search.aspx. Is there a way to achieve that?

after digging deeper, there is a request to https://substrate.office.com/search/api/v2/query with post body:

```
 "EntityRequests": [
    {
      "EntityType": "External",
      "ContentSources": [
        "ExternalSource"
      ],
      "From": 0,
      "Size": 10,
      "Query": {
        "QueryString": "*",
        "DisplayQueryString": "*",
        "QueryTemplate": "{searchTerms}"
      },
      "Sort": [
        {
          "Field": "Score",
          "SortDirection": "Desc"
        }
      ],
      "BypassResultTypes": false,
      "PreferredResultSourceFormat": "AdaptiveCardTemplateBinding",
      "HitHighlight": {
        "HitHighlightedProperties": [
          "HitHighlightedSummary"
        ],
        "SummaryLength": 200
      }
    }
  ]
```

the right question is - is there a way to manipulate this post data in any way?